# Ado file, syntax for several variable groups

Tags: stata

I wish to create an `ado` file, which has four categories of variables.

The idea is that the user can input something like:

```
myprog depvar biggroup, ingroup(varlist1) outgroup(varlist2)
```

In this example `depvar` and `biggroup` are single variables, while `ingroup` is at least two variables and the `outgroup` is the same but optional.

So far i have attempted the following:

```
program myprog, rclass
    version 15
    syntax varlist(min=2 max=2), ingroup(min=2) [outgroup]
    local depvar: word 1 of `varlist'
    ...
end
```

I can pull apart `varlist` based on `word count` to create the `depvar` and `biggroup` variables as I did for `depvar`.

However, I am unsure how to create the additional lists for `ingroup` and `outgroup`. The issue is that they can both include a varied number of variables and I do not know how to differentiate them with either the `syntax` or `args` commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a `varlist` for each option. Or alternatively you could pass them as strings.

Here's the solution using a `varlist`:

```
capture program drop myprog
program define myprog, rclass
    version 14
    syntax varlist(min=2 max=2), ingroup(varlist min=2) [outgroup(varlist min=2)]
    display ""
    display "`varlist'"
    display ""
    display "`ingroup'"
    display ""
    display "`outgroup'"
end

. clear

. generate one = runiform()
. generate two = runiform()
. generate three = runiform()
. generate four = runiform()
. generate five = runiform()
. generate six = runiform()
. generate seven = runiform()

. myprog one two, ingroup(three four) outgroup(five six seven)

one two

three four

five six seven
```

Comment: This is very clear. As an extension: is there a way to allow ingroup to have a conditional minimum? For example, if I need the number of variables (ingroup+ougroup)>=2, is this feasible?

Comment: Off the top of my head i think it is possible. In this case you will need to pass everything as strings and then within the program unpack each `varlist` and code whatever condition you have in mind manually.